# Is "arcore_flutter_plugin" not compatible with the latest "ARcore SDK for Android (Ver1.22.0)"?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

It was successful in Ver1.11.0.

Is there any other way to run arcore on flutter?

arcore_flutter_plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin

ARcore SDK
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore

/android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // Provides ArFragment, and other UX resources.
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0'
    // Alternatively, use ArSceneView without the UX dependency.
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.15.0'

    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.22.0'
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  arkit_plugin: any
  native_screenshot: ^0.0.5
  arcore_flutter_plugin: ^0.0.10
```

build errors

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[com.google.ar:core:1.22.0] /Users/~/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/~/core-1.22.0/AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-54 Error:
    Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.google.ar:core:1.22.0] AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-54
[com.google.ar:core:1.22.0] /Users/~/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/~/core-1.22.0/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully use an Android Library based on ARCore 1.22.0 in my flutter app. Make sure you have `implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'` in your android apps build.gradle and use an appropriate gradle wrapper version.

Comment: \flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (241, 38): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onActivityCreated(@NonNull p0: Activity, @Nullable p1: Bundle?): Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
e: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (242, 13): 'onActivityCreated' overides nothing

Comment: Any Luck With This Error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with creating a new project then

There is an error in the flutter plugin that needs to be corrected.

Go to ArCoreView.kt file in Flutter plugin at

\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.flutter-io.cn\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin

remove "?" from onActivityCreated as below

i.e.
Replace
override fun onActivityCreated( activity: Activity?, savedInstanceState: Bundle? )
By
override fun onActivityCreated( activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle? )

This resolved my problem